# Find an element with a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where I've multiple **div** with class **navToME on/off**. Now what I've trying to do here is if a **div** has a class **off**, then remove the class **navToMe**.

E.g.,

```
if($('.navToME').hasClass('off')){
   $('.off').removeClass('navToME');  
}
```

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="on navToME">
            <strong>ABC</strong>
        </div>
<div class="off navToME">
            <strong>DEF</strong>
        </div>
```

What's happening right now is it just checks the first **div** with that class and returns **false**. Is there a way anyone can suggest so that I could just this for all **classes** inside my HTML? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use Class Selector to identify element with multiple class then use `removeClass()`

```
$('.off.navToME').removeClass('navToME');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.off.navToME').removeClass('navToME');
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}
.off {
  background-color: red;
}
.navToME {
  background-color: grey!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="on navToME">
  <strong>ABC</strong>
</div>
<div class="off navToME">
  <strong>DEF</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: @stapal, actually I'm working with Backbone. So I'm handling the jquery functionality inside my VIEW but it should but it's not.